# Can't iterate through a combobox from a focused textbox

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combobox with an indefinite items in the list, so it is not certain how many items are in there. I always have my focus on a textbox and what I want to achieve is change the selected index of the combo box when I press up or down. But unfortunately I'm doing something wrong again.

```
private void txtbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
  {
    while (combo.SelectedIndex <= combo.Items.Count)
    {
      if (combo.SelectedIndex >= combo.Items.Count)
      {
        break;
      }
      combo.SelectedIndex++
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that:

```
private void txtbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  // Use "e.Modifiers == Keys.None" 
  // if you want just Down Arrow and not, say, Alt + Down; Shift + Down etc.
  if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) && (e.Modifiers == Keys.None)) {
    // We don't need default behaviour whatever it is
    e.Handled = true;
    ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;

    // If selected index is not the last one, select the next item
    if (combo != null)
      if (combo.SelectedIndex < (combo.Items.Count - 1))    
        combo.SelectedIndex += 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
{
   if(combo.SelectedIndex+1 <= combo.Items.Count)
    {
       combo.SelectedIndex++
    }
   else
    {
     //show warning here;
    }
}
```